# Transfer at Beijing flying on separate ticket

Tags: tickets, airport-transfer

I will be travelling to China (Lanzhou) from Mumbai (BOM) and I plan on booking two separate tickets
since its cheaper.

Actually I have already booked the final leg of my journey. 
Below are the details:

[image]

For the initial part of my trip, I have two options for reaching PEK.

Option a)

[image]

Option b)

[image]

So what are your thoughts on these two options. If I choose options b) then is there sufficient time for the transfer from international to domestic at PEK.

Also since CA and SQ are both Star Alliance member is it possible that my luggage can be checked all the way through to LHW.

If you spot any potential problem in the above itinerary then please let me know. I will be having an Indian passport with Z-type single entry Chinese visa with 000 days validity.

Comment: In option b, considering there are seven hours between your touchdown at PEK at 2300 and your domestic flight from PEK at 0605, why is having sufficient time a concern? Shouldn't seven hours be enough, unless there's something I'm missing here?

Also, "000 days validity" is a typo, right?

Comment: I have opted for option b. I guess it should be enough but I just wanted to confirm from fellow travellers. And that's not a typo. Z type employment Chinese visa will have 000 days printed. It essentially means that the no of days are undecided. On the visa it's also written that I have to apply for a residence permit within 30 days of arrival. So in effect the actual visa will be the residence permit which will have the non zero duration of stay.